# Using mocha's async 'done' function alongside angular's injector

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js

I find myself unable to figure out how to use mocha's async done function with angulars injector. I've tried stuff like this:

```
describe('myService', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    describe('action()', function() {
        var obj = {};
        before(function(done) {
            obj.done = done;
        });

        it('calls a function async', inject(function(myService) {
            myService.calledAsync = function() {
                obj.done()
             };

             myService.action();
        });

    });
});
```

But that doesn't work because the `it` function is never run. So the `before` just times out.

I've also tried wrapping inject around the second argument to describe and running the entire test body inside the before function (as suggested by tj here: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/253). But that gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$modules' of null`.

Does anyone have a method for making this work?

Comment: Use a nested `inject` function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28761027/3790806

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main issues you need to fix are 1. Don't try to save `done` during `before` and call it later and 2. Move the `inject` off the `it` up to the `beforeEach` so your `it` can be just `function(done) {` as normal.

Here's the layout boilerplate that is working for me:

```
describe('myService', function () {
  // declare injected variables here so they are available to tests
  // via closure
  var httpBackend, rootScope, controller, myService;

  // Then mock out your module with a beforeEach
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  // inject another beforeEach to get what you need
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, _myService_) {
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    controller = $controller;
    myService = _myService_;
    });
  });

  // Just an example
  afterEach(function() {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  // Do a regular `it` function
  it('should ', function(done) {
    myService.calledAsync = function() {
      done();
    };
    myService.action();
  });
});
```

A few misc tips from your snippet:

- Don't try to store a reference to `done`. Each lifecycle point is distinct, so if mocha gives you a `done` function in `beforeEach` that has the semantic "beforeEach is done when this gets called", so if you try to save it and call it later inside `it` mocha's control flow will get messed up.
- Mocha is mostly functional style and not OO method style, so assigning `done` to an object and calling it like a method is not necessary or intended. You can just call `done()` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter, I was confusing myself because I normally use the tdd interface (setUp etc) however: AUGHGGH, there is some weirdness if you use the actual name of your service as the variable... Which I see you are not doing in your example, but which took me forever to realise I was doing. Thank you!