# Writing Karma + Mocha tests with both dependency injection and `done`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

What's the most elegant way to write Karma unit tests in mocha that both have dependency injection and `done`?

Dependency injection:

```
describe('cows', function(){
  it('farts a lot', inject(function(cow){
    // do stuff
  }))
})
```

Done:

```
describe('cows', function(){
  it('farts a lot', function(done){
    // do stuff
  })
})
```

What if I want both `cow` and `done` available in my unit test? Right now, this is what I'm doing, and it's unsatisfactory.

```
beforeEach(inject(function(cow){
  this.cow = cow;
}))

it('farts a lot', function(done){
  this.cow // etc
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can nested function *inject* into test function

```
it("should nested inject function into test function", function(done) {
    inject(function($timeout) {

      $timeout(function() {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        done();
      }, 10);

      $timeout.flush(10);

    });    
  });
```

*inject* is global function defined in [ngMock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject) module and can be used anywhere in the test.